# Android get User Position after restart device

Tags: android, geolocation, locationmanager, android-location

In my app I'm trying to find the position from the device. My Code work's great:

```
boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

if(isGPSEnabled || isNetworkEnabled)
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(isGPSEnabled ? LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER : LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

But after restart my device I don't get a location anymore. I tried it with another device. The code works, after restart I get null for my location... What is this?

Even after open google Maps, which found my position, I don't get the position...

Is it normal? Is there some workaround or something like this?

EDIT:

I don't use a LocationListener. I just use the code above in a asyntask for getting the position one time. I don't want to track the position the whole time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that if the GPS is enabled but has not been called yet, you take it's location instead of the Network location (which is what you should take in that case).
I would switch your entire block of code with that:

`Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location == null) location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);`